# Having the parameters of a matrix be read in?

Tags: c++, matrix, parameters

So part of my homework is to write a program where the parameters of a 2D array are read in.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define ROWCAP 100
#define COLCAP 100
using namespace std;
void readValues(int x, int y, double matrix[x][y]);
void printValues(int x, int y, double matrix[x][y]);
int main() {
    int row;
    int cols;

    cout<<"Enter the number of rows: ";
    cin>>row;
    while(row>ROWCAP){
        cout<<"Number is too large, try again: ";
        cin>>row;
    }
    cout<<"Enter the number of columns: ";
    cin>>cols;
    while(cols>COLCAP){
        cout<<"Number is too large, try again: ";
        cin>>cols;
    }
    double matrix[row][cols];
    cout<<"Enter the matrix: \n";
    readValues(row,cols,matrix[row][cols]);
    cout<<"\nThe matrix entered was:\n";
    printValues(row,cols,matrix[row][cols])
    return 0;
}

void readValues(int x, int y, double matrix[x][y])
{
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<y; j++)
        {
            cin>>matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void printValues(int x, int y, double matrix[x][y])
{
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<y; j++)
        {
            cout<<matrix[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

These are the errors:

```
error: 'matrix' declared as array of references of type 'double &'
void readValues(int x, int y, double &matrix[x][y]);
```

I've been stuck on this for three hours. What am I doing wrong?
P.S. Can only use iostream

Comment: `define` -> `#define` and `void readValues(int x, int y, double &matrix[x][y]);` -> `void readValues(int x, int y, double matrix[x][y]);` (you declare the array in `main()`, just pass it, not a pointer to it)

Comment: `double matrix[row][cols];` -- there are no VLAs (*Variable Length Arrays*) in C++ (except by non-standard compiler extension). Why not use a vector of vectors? If you must use plain `double` then you will need to allocate dynamically or declare `double matrix[ROWCAP][COLCAP];` and operate only on the space defined by `row, col` (which has its disadvantages, but doable)

Comment: Do not edit your question to incorporate an answer you got in comments, to then switch to a different question, that is considered a moving target question (and really not appreciated in case you already got an official answer..). If you do at least adapt all of the question, too, so that it still fits the new question. I.e. post the correct error message you now get, not the old ones. Please [edit] your question again to fix that, instead of explaining a new question in a comment on the partially old one.

Comment: So you DID learn about Variable Length Arrays and their special non-portable aspects? You DID already learn about the assumptions on the used compiler which that implies? If not but you have already learned about normal arrays which all compilers know to create, but require a static size definition, then use them. It is quite difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a two-dimensional array name as an argument or a formal parameter. When you define a shape parameter group in the called function, you can refer to

To determine the size of all dimensions, you can also omit the size description of the first dimension, such as:
     `void Func(int array[3][10]);`
     `void Func(int array[][10]);`
     Both are legal and equivalent, but you cannot omit the size of the second or higher dimension.

```
#include <iostream>
#define ROWCAP 100
#define COLCAP 100

using namespace std;
double matrix[ROWCAP][COLCAP];
void readValues(int x, int y, double matrix[][100]);
void printValues(int x, int y, double matrix[][100]);

int main() {

    int row;

    int cols;

    cout << "Enter the number of rows: ";
    cin >> row;
    while (row > ROWCAP) {
        cout << "Number is too large, try again: ";
        cin >> row;
    }
    cout << "Enter the number of columns: ";
    cin >> cols;
    while (cols > COLCAP) {
        cout << "Number is too large, try again: ";
        cin >> cols;
    }

    cout << "Enter the matrix: \n";
    readValues(row, cols, matrix);
    cout << "\nThe matrix entered was:\n";
    printValues(row, cols, matrix);
    return 0;
}

void readValues(int x, int y, double matrix[][100])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            cin >> matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void printValues(int x, int y, double matrix[][100])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

By the way:
(1) The parameter is a two-dimensional array, but the dimension of the second dimension is specified.

`int array[10][10];`

Function declaration: `void fuc(int a[][10]);`

Function call: `fuc(array);`

- In the function fuc, a is a two-dimensional array. Use the `a[i][j]` form to access elements in the array.

(2) The parameter uses a one-dimensional pointer array.

```
Int *array[10];

For(i = 0; i < 10; i++)

Array[i] = new int[10];
```

Function declaration: `void fuc(int *a[10]);`

Function call: `fuc(array);`

- In the function fuc, a is a one-dimensional array of pointers. Use the `*(a[i] + j)` form to access the elements in the array.

(3) The pointer of the parameter uses the pointer.

```
Int **array;

Array = new int *[10];

For(i = 0; i <10; i++)

Array[i] = new int[10];
```

Function declaration: `void fuc(int **a);`

Function call: `fuc(array);`

- In the function fuc, a is a pointer to a pointer. Use the `*(int *)(a + i*d2 + j)` form to access elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If your assignment is to use arrays and nothing more, an array must be declared with an integer literal setting the number of elements for each dimension, e.g.

```
int main() {

    double matrix[ROWCAP][COLCAP];
```

Initialize your variables to make your initial comparisons work for you:

```
    int row = 101;
    int col = 101;

    while (row > ROWCAP) {
        cout << "\nEnter the number of rows: ";
        if (!(cin >> row)) {
            cerr << "error: invalid integer input - row\n";
            return 1;
        }
        if (row <= ROWCAP)
            break;
        cerr << "error: exceeds " << ROWCAP << '\n';
    }
```

(same for `col` with `COLCAP`, **note:** you can simply loop continually until you get the input you require, e.g. `while (1) {...}`)

To pass a 2D array to a function, you have 2 options:

```
void readValues(int x, int y, double matrix[][COLCAP]);
```

or

```
void readValues(int x, int y, double (*matrix)[COLCAP]);
```

The corresponding function *definition* would be:

```
void readValues (int x, int y, double matrix[][COLCAP])
{
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<y; j++)
        {
            if (!(cin >> matrix[i][j])) {
                cerr << "error: invalid integer input - matrix[i][j]\n";
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or with

```
void readValues (int x, int y, double (*matrix)[COLCAP])
```

(**note:** you must ***Validate Every User Input***)

When you call a function passing a 2D array, you pass the name of the array only:

```
    cout << "Enter the matrix:\n";
    readValues (row, col, matrix);
```

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>

#define ROWCAP 100
#define COLCAP 100

using namespace std;

void readValues(int x, int y, double matrix[][COLCAP]);
void printValues(int x, int y, double matrix[][COLCAP]);

int main() {

    double matrix[ROWCAP][COLCAP];
    int row = 101;
    int col = 101;

    while (row > ROWCAP) {
        cout << "\nEnter the number of rows: ";
        if (!(cin >> row)) {
            cerr << "error: invalid integer input - row\n";
            return 1;
        }
        if (row <= ROWCAP)
            break;
        cerr << "error: exceeds " << ROWCAP << '\n';
    }

    while (col > COLCAP) {
        cout << "\nEnter the number of cols: ";
        if (!(cin >> col)) {
            cerr << "error: invalid integer input - col\n";
            return 1;
        }
        if (col <= COLCAP)
            break;
        cerr << "error: exceeds " << COLCAP << '\n';
    }

    cout << "Enter the matrix:\n";
    readValues (row, col, matrix);
    cout<<"\nThe matrix entered was:\n";
    printValues (row, col, matrix);
    return 0;
}

void readValues (int x, int y, double matrix[][COLCAP])
{
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<y; j++)
        {
            if (!(cin >> matrix[i][j])) {
                cerr << "error: invalid integer input - matrix[i][j]\n";
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
}

void printValues (int x, int y, double matrix[][COLCAP])
{
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<y; j++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/matrix_cin

Enter the number of rows: 3

Enter the number of cols: 3
Enter the matrix:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

The matrix entered was:
1       2       3
4       5       6
7       8       9
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

See the problem main problem with this approach is VLA(variable size array).
Read this

> The dimension must be known at compile-time, which means that the dimension must be a constant expression.
>   But in your case, you are using x and y to create an array whose values will be known at runtime. Your are lucky that your compiler allows you to do so. But remeber these VLA are not supported in C++.

All you can do is -

```
double matrix[100][100]; // declare it globally. Btw it's your choice it can be inside function. Notice we have provided the size at compiler time(100).
void readValues(int x, int y, double matrix[][100]); 
void printValues(int x, int y, double matrix[][100]);
int main() {
    int row;
    int cols;

    cout<<"Enter the number of rows: ";
    cin>>row;
    while(row>ROWCAP){
        cout<<"Number is too large, try again: ";
        cin>>row;
    }
    cout<<"Enter the number of columns: ";
    cin>>cols;
    while(cols>COLCAP){
        cout<<"Number is too large, try again: ";
        cin>>cols;
    }

    cout<<"Enter the matrix: \n";
    readValues(row,cols,matrix); // Just pass it like normal argument.
    cout<<"\nThe matrix entered was:\n";
    printValues(row,cols,matrix);
    return 0;
}

void readValues(int x, int y, double matrix[][100]) //
{
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<y; j++)
        {
            cin>>matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void printValues(int x, int y, double matrix[][100])
{
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<y; j++)
        {
            cout<<matrix[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Enter the number of rows: 3
Enter the number of columns: 3
Enter the matrix:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

The matrix entered was:
1       2       3
4       5       6
7       8       9

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 7.435 s
Press any key to continue.
```

**EDIT** - I noticed that your teacher asked to use a const global row and column. SO you must do like this.

```
const int row = 100;
const int column = 100;
double matrix[row][column]; // Now you can do this as row and column are const. before it was error.
void readValues(int x, int y, double matrix[][100]);
void printValues(int x, int y, double matrix[][100]);
int main() {
    int roww, colss;
    cout<<"Enter the number of rows: ";
    cin>>roww;
    while(roww>row){
        cout<<"Number is too large, try again: ";
        cin>>roww;
    }
    cout<<"Enter the number of columns: ";
    cin>>colss;
    while(colss>column){
        cout<<"Number is too large, try again: ";
        cin>>colss;
    }
    double matrix[100][100];
    cout<<"Enter the matrix: \n";
    readValues(roww,colss,matrix);
    cout<<"\nThe matrix entered was:\n";
    printValues(roww,colss,matrix);
    return 0;
}

void readValues(int x, int y, double matrix[][100])
{
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<y; j++)
        {
            cin>>matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void printValues(int x, int y, double matrix[][100])
{
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<y; j++)
        {
            cout<<matrix[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```